# Are linux shell pipes pipelined?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh, zsh

Given a file *input.txt* if I do something like

```
grep pattern1 input.txt | grep pattern2 | wc -l
```

is the output from the first command continuously passed (as soon as it is generated) as input to the second command?

Or does the pipe wait until the first command finishes to start running the second command?

Comment: Hmm. It's hard to say whether this can be described as a duplicate of questions whose cause is a contrary assumption (we have rather a lot of those).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, they're pipelined -- each component's stdout is connected to the stdin of the next via a FIFO, and all components are started in parallel.

---

This is why

```
cat some-file | ...tools... >some-file
```

...typically results in a truncated file: Because the pipeline is started all at once, the last piece (truncating `some-file` for write) happens before `cat` has finished (or often, even started) reading the file from input.

Answer (score 7):

The general answer to your question is "yes".

**HOWEVER**, some programs, [such as `grep` itself](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/009), buffer their results up to some arbitrary point. They may include options to disable this buffering, but you should not rely on them being available.

Comment: "Until the input has been processed" makes this untrue. Common implementations of `grep` buffer at more than a per-line level, but that buffer **is not indefinite**: It is **absolutely not guaranteed** that all input is processed before any output is received.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Corrected.

Comment: It's also untrue to imply that it's no longer buffered after that point. Content is still buffered -- the buffer has simply filled and been flushed at least once. Processing very large files is where the performance gains from avoiding unnecessary `flush` calls (as using a buffer that isn't line-oriented permits) are most compelling, so to disable it in that case as a default behavior would be entirely counterproductive.

Comment: ...so, buffering is simply an implementation detail around when `flush()` is called, and thus on what boundaries the reads and writes are broken up into syscalls. It's only cases where the input side of the pipeline is reading content slowly enough that the delay while the buffer fills becomes pertinent to resource utilization that this is a caveat rather than a (substantial) enhancement to performance.

Answer (score 2):

Piped commands run concurrently.

This is very commonly used to allow the second program to process data as it comes out from the first program, before the first program has completed its operation. For example

```
grep pattern huge-file | tr a-z A-Z
```

begins to display the matching lines in uppercase even before grep has finished traversing the large file.

Similarly

```
grep pattern huge-file | head -n 1
```

displays the first matching line, and may stop processing well before grep has finished reading its input file.

These two examples which I can think of explains that they run concurrently.